# ¿Alguien entendiende el método .readline de python?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente programa que lee un archivo .fasta pero no logro entender el trasfondo del funcionamiento del método utilizado ya que no le estoy dando parámetros diferentes, sin emabrgo el método me lee cada línea correctamente. Es decir, el programa me funciona bien, pero no logro entender el por qué sin darle parámetros nuevos,el método sabe que tiene que saltar a la nueva línea.

`````
unalinea = F1.readline()
print ("La línea 1 es: %s" % ( unalinea))
unalinea = F1.readline()
print ("La línea 2 es: %s" % ( unalinea))
unalinea = F1.readline()
print ("La línea 3 es: %s" % ( unalinea))
F1.close()````
`````

Comment: Amigo estoy aprendiendo Python y no creo que el error este en el método readline(). A mi vista cada vez que haces uso del metodo print() este por default hace salto de linea.

Comment: el método `readline` es un iterador,  lo que quiere decir que cada vez que sea llamado pasará a la siguiente línea automáticamente. Si has visto algo de C te resultará fácil entenderlo